# ImageSource from base64 string in Nativescript

Tags: base64, nativescript, imagesource

I can't figure out at all how to create an [ImageSource](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource.html) from a base64 string.

`let source = new ImageSource();
source.fromBase64('b64strhere').then(..);`

in this context the parameter passed in the following promise is a  boolean which I don't know what's supposed to represent. The ImageSource afterwards is null both on android and iOS.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I load it and put in an Image element like this:

```
this.imageSource = new ImageSource();
var loadedBase64 = this.imageSource.loadFromBase64(MY_BASE_64_STRING_PREVIOUSLY_SAVED);
console.log(loadedBase64);
if (loadedBase64) {
    let photo = <Image>this.photoImage.nativeElement;
    photo.imageSource = this.imageSource;
    this.photo = photo;
}
```

(NS 3.1)

Comment: Apparently my mistake was having the mimetype in the base64 string and it was returning false. Marking you as an answer since it's a good code sample on how to use the ImageSource class.